# Python 3.5.1 pip install 'ImportError'

Tags: pip, urllib

While using pip install I am getting the following error:

Error while finding spec for 'pip__main__' <: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package>; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Any advice on this one?

I thought maybe it was related to the requests module itself but I tried to download other modules and had the same problem.

Comment: I did figure this out eventually.  I was practicing some urllib functions and named a file urllib.py.  When I called pip it found my practice file rather than the actual module file.  So for myself and other inexperienced programmers in the future avoid using the names of any included functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded from Python 3.3 to v3.5.1 on Windows and hit the same error message. I understand it's not the same as your problem.

It seems that the instructions from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) to use:

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

are wrong, at least for Windows because I get the error message quoted by the OP.

I forgot to add the Scripts directory to my path, the same as previous releases. When I add it the problem is fixed. My path now has (for a default install of Python 3.5):

```
PATH=<blah>;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts
```

The pip executable is located in Scripts, so pip commands can now be executed directly, the same as always:

```
pip install urllib
```